# Why is dpkg -i faster than the ubuntu software center?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, software-center, dpkg

Why is using `sudo dpkg -i package.deb` to install deb packages faster than double clicking on the deb file and installing it through the software center?

I have seen a very significant time gap between the two ways. While `dpkg -i` takes a few seconds at most to install a package the software center can easily take a few minutes.

What is software center doing behind the scenes which makes it slow? From my understanding, Software Center was just a GUI layer on top of `dpkg -i`.

Comment: Using a gui is sometimes like turning on a light switch using a broom handle :)

Comment: How powerful is your computer?

Comment: yes, via the software center it is very slow, the terminal is the quickest but gdebi also gives decent speed

Comment: @DKBose - i7-5820K (6 Core Haswell-E) with 16GB DDR4. Same performance difference with my another i7-3610QM and 8GB DDR3.

Comment: One cause could be that `dpkg -i` does no dependency checks and installations but Software Center does? Maybe `dpkg -i` also lacks some more integrity checks etc...